# Implementation of config file

Tags: c++, configuration

I am making an application in C++, and it requires a config file that will be read and interpreted on launch. It will contain things such as:

```
Module1=true
```

Now, my original plan was to store it all in variables and simply have

```
If(module1) {
    DO_STUFF();
}
```

However this seems wasteful as it would be checking constantly for a value that would never change. Any ideas?

Comment: If you really need the highest efficiency, include the flag in compilation settings as a constant, compile-time value. If you need to choose which flags to use on startup of the program, compile different versions of the program, put them in the same folder, and make  launcher script that reads the config file and starts the right executable.

Comment: compilers are very good at optimising away redundant tests. If the optimiser  can see that module1 is an invariant, not an alias and not volatile with -O2 it will do its very best to only test it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimize the code, only if you find a bottleneck with a profiler. **Branch prediction** *should* do its thing here, `module1` never changes, so if you call it in a loop, even, there *shouldn't* be a noticeable performance loss.

If you want to experiment, you can branch once, and make a pointer point to the right function:

```
using func_ptr = void (*)();
func_ptr p = [](){};

if(module1)
    p = DO_STUFF;

while(...)
    p();
```

But this is just something to profile, look at the assembly...

There are also slower, but comfortable ways you could be storing the configuration, e.g. in an array with enumerated indexes, or a map. If I were to get some value in a loop, I'd do:

```
auto module1 = modules[MODULE1];        // array and enumeration
//auto module1 = modules.at("module1"); // map and string

while(...)
{
    if(module1)
        DO_STUFF;

    ...
}
```

So I'd end up with what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

performance wise a boolean check is no problem, except you start doing it millions or billions of times. Maybe you can start merging code which belongs to module1, but other than that you'd have to check for it like you currently do

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't an issue. If your program requires that `Module1` should be true then let it check the value and continue on. It wont affect your performance unless it is being checked too many times.

One thing you could do is make an inline function if it being checked too many times. However, you will have to make sure the function shouldnt be too big otherwise it will be a bigger bottleneck

Comment: See it will be called in an infinite loop and it seemed wasteful to check it on each iteration.

Comment: Say even if it were not going to check the value, would you still have to execute the code? If yes then it wont matter. You could also loop it in a while loop `while(Module1`)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, didn't spot this when I looked it up:
[MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx)
So I check the boolean once on launch and then I don't need to anymore as only the correct functions are launched.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your program is set up and how the variables change the behaviour of the code you might be able to use function pointers:

```
if(Module1 == true)
{
   std::function<void(int)> DoStuff = Module1Stuff;
}
```

And then later:

```
while(true)
{
    DoStuff(ImportantVariable);
}
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function for further reference.

Not that I think it'll help all that much but it's an alternative to try out at least.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved if you know the all use cases of the values you check. For example, if you've read your config file and `module1` is `true` - you do one thing, if it is `false` - another. Let's start with example:

```
class ConfigFileWorker {
    public:
        virtual void run() = 0;
};

class WithModule1Worker {
    public:
        void run() final override {
            // do stuff as if your `Module1` is true
        }
};

class WithoutModule1Worker {
    public:
        void run() final override {
            // do stuff as if your `Module1` is false
        }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<ConfigFileWorker> worker;
    const bool Module1 = read_config_file(file, "Module1");
    if (Module1) { // you check this only once during launch and just use `worker` all the time after
        worker.reset(new WithModule1Worker);
    } else {
        worker.reset(new WithoutModule1Worker);
    }

    // here and after just use the pointer with `run()` - then you will not need to check the variable all the time, you'll just perform action.
}
```

So you have predefined behaviour for 2 cases (`true` and `false`) and just create an object of one of them during parsing the config file on launch. This is `java-like` code, but of course you may use function pointers, `std::function` and other abstractions instead of a base class, however, base class-option has more flexibility in my opinion.